# Time to first block

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, android

I am experience long waiting times from start of the block-sync to the first block. Is there any way I can speed this up?

```
02-08 17:21:37.971 23640 23659 E GoLog   : I0208 16:21:37.980483 eth/downloader/downloader.go:326] Block synchronisation started
02-08 17:23:49.301 23640 23659 E GoLog   : I0208 16:23:49.318190 core/headerchain.go:342] imported   74 headers in 2m10.152s. #497051 [a8c9ba00… / 38f76ccb…]
```

this is using the in-process node from "org.ethereum:geth:1.5.8" on a galaxy note 4. Perhaps there is some setting to speed this up? This way it is not the best user-experience.

Comment: What command have you used to start `geth`?

Comment: I am using the in-process node - so I did not start it via cli

Comment: Ah, yes, apologies. In which case, good question :) (For others looking at this, details here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile-Clients:-Libraries-and-Inproc-Ethereum-Nodes)